# Timeout error in Databricks distributed training example notebook

Tags: python, pytorch, databricks, distributed-computing, aws-databricks

I am following along with this [notebook](https://docs.databricks.com/en/_extras/notebooks/source/deep-learning/torch-distributor-notebook.html) found from this [article](https://docs.databricks.com/en/machine-learning/train-model/distributed-training/spark-pytorch-distributor.html). I am attempting to fine tune the model with a single node and 4 GPUs. In code block 3, I change the variable db_host to the url in my address bar, both including and excluding the `https://`. I then change NUM_WORKERS in the 5th code block to 1. I then run code block 6, 10, and then 14.

I am then greeted with the error:
`RuntimeError: TorchDistributor failed during training. View stdout logs for detailed error message.`
Here is the full traceback:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-2821949673242080>:5
      3 NUM_PROCESSES = torch.cuda.device_count()
      4 print(f"We're using {NUM_PROCESSES} GPUs")
----> 5 single_node_multi_gpu_ckpt_path = TorchDistributor(num_processes=NUM_PROCESSES, local_mode=True, use_gpu=USE_GPU).run(train_model)

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/databricks/utils/instrumentation.py:43, in instrumented.<locals>.wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
     41 try:
     42     start_time = time.time()
---> 43     return_val = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
     44 except Exception as e:
     45     duration = (time.time() - start_time) * 1000

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/torch/distributor.py:805, in TorchDistributor.run(self, train_object, *args)
    801     framework_wrapper_fn = (
    802         TorchDistributor._run_training_on_pytorch_function  # type: ignore
    803     )
    804 if self.local_mode:
--> 805     output = self._run_local_training(framework_wrapper_fn, train_object, *args)
    806 else:
    807     output = self._run_distributed_training(framework_wrapper_fn, train_object, *args)

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/torch/distributor.py:508, in TorchDistributor._run_local_training(self, framework_wrapper_fn, train_object, *args)
    505         os.environ[CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES] = ",".join(selected_gpus)
    507     self.logger.info(f"Started local training with {self.num_processes} processes")
--> 508     output = framework_wrapper_fn(self.input_params, train_object, *args)
    509     self.logger.info(f"Finished local training with {self.num_processes} processes")
    511 finally:

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/torch/distributor.py:711, in TorchDistributor._run_training_on_pytorch_function(input_params, train_fn, *args)
    709 TorchDistributor._run_training_on_pytorch_file(input_params, train_file_path, *args)
    710 if not os.path.exists(output_file_path):
--> 711     raise RuntimeError(
    712         "TorchDistributor failed during training. "
    713         "View stdout logs for detailed error message."
    714     )
    715 try:
    716     output = TorchDistributor._get_pickled_output(output_file_path)

RuntimeError: TorchDistributor failed during training. View stdout logs for detailed error message.
```

And here is the full output (I replaced my Databricks workspace name and experiment name with placeholders) (some abbreviation/abridging to satisfy character limit):

```
WARNING:__main__:
Setting OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable for each process to be 1 in default, to avoid your system being overloaded, please further tune the variable for optimal performance in your application as needed.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 239, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1283, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1329, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1278, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1038, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 976, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 205, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 179, in _new_conn
    raise ConnectTimeoutError(
urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff00d322f80>, 'Connection to $DATABRICKS_HOST_URL timed out. (connect timeout=120)')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='$DATABRICKS_HOST_URL', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/get-by-name?experiment_name=%EXPERIMENTNAME%2Fpytorch-distributor (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff00d322f80>, 'Connection to $DATABRICKS_HOST_URL timed out. (connect timeout=120)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='$DATABRICKS_HOST_URL', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/get-by-name?experiment_name=%EXPERIMENTNAME%2Fpytorch-distributor (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff00d322f80>, 'Connection to $DATABRICKS_HOST_URL timed out. (connect timeout=120)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/utils/rest_utils.py", line 105, in http_request
    raise MlflowException(
mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: API request to http://$DATABRICKS_HOST_URL/api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/get-by-name failed with timeout exception HTTPConnectionPool(host='$DATABRICKS_HOST_URL', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/get-by-name?experiment_name=%EXPERIMENTNAME%2Fpytorch-distributor (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff00d322f80>, 'Connection to $DATABRICKS_HOST_URL timed out. (connect timeout=120)')). To increase the timeout, set the environment variable MLFLOW_HTTP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT (default: 120, type: int) to a larger value.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "...", line 95, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "...", line 85, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "...", line 398, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "...", line 239, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1283, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "...", line 1329, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "...", line 1278, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "...", line 1038, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "...", line 976, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 205, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "...", line 179, in _new_conn
    raise ConnectTimeoutError(
urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f178552af80>, 'Connection to $DATABRICKS_HOST_URL timed out. (connect timeout=120)')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File ".../connectionpool.py", line 815, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "...", line 815, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "...", line 815, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  [Previous line repeated 2 more times]
  File "...", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='$DATABRICKS_HOST_URL', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/get-by-name?experiment_name=%EXPERIMENTNAME%2Fpytorch-distributor (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f178552af80>, 'Connection to $DATABRICKS_HOST_URL timed out. (connect timeout=120)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='$DATABRICKS_HOST_URL', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/get-by-name?experiment_name=%EXPERIMENTNAME%2Fpytorch-distributor (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f178552af80>, 'Connection to $DATABRICKS_HOST_URL timed out. (connect timeout=120)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmpc8dg8q7l/train.py", line 8, in <module>
    output = train_fn(*args)
  File "<command-3105697028983166>", line 46, in main_fn
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/fluent.py", line 126, in set_experiment
    experiment = client.get_experiment_by_name(experiment_name)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/client.py", line 507, in get_experiment_by_name
    return self._tracking_client.get_experiment_by_name(name)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/_tracking_service/client.py", line 222, in get_experiment_by_name
    return self.store.get_experiment_by_name(name)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/store/tracking/rest_store.py", line 307, in get_experiment_by_name
    response_proto = self._call_endpoint(GetExperimentByName, req_body)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/store/tracking/rest_store.py", line 59, in _call_endpoint
    return call_endpoint(self.get_host_creds(), endpoint, method, json_body, response_proto)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/utils/rest_utils.py", line 197, in call_endpoint
    response = http_request(**call_kwargs)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/utils/rest_utils.py", line 105, in http_request
    raise MlflowException(
mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: API request to http://$DATABRICKS_HOST_URL/api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/get-by-name failed with timeout exception HTTPConnectionPool(host='$DATABRICKS_HOST_URL', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/get-by-name?experiment_name=%EXPERIMENTNAME%2Fpytorch-distributor (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f178552af80>, 'Connection to $DATABRICKS_HOST_URL timed out. (connect timeout=120)')). To increase the timeout, set the environment variable MLFLOW_HTTP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT (default: 120, type: int) to a larger value.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1283, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1329, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1278, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1038, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 976, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 205, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 179, in _new_conn
    raise ConnectTimeoutError(
urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fc83932af80>, 'Connection to $DATABRICKS_HOST_URL timed out. (connect timeout=120)')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='$DATABRICKS_HOST_URL', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/get-by-name?experiment_name=%EXPERIMENTNAME%2Fpytorch-distributor (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fc83932af80>, 'Connection to $DATABRICKS_HOST_URL timed out. (connect timeout=120)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 553, in send
    raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='$DATABRICKS_HOST_URL', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/get-by-name?experiment_name=%EXPERIMENTNAME%2Fpytorch-distributor (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fc83932af80>, 'Connection to $DATABRICKS_HOST_URL timed out. (connect timeout=120)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmpc8dg8q7l/train.py", line 8, in <module>
    output = train_fn(*args)
  File "<command-3105697028983166>", line 46, in main_fn
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/fluent.py", line 126, in set_experiment
    experiment = client.get_experiment_by_name(experiment_name)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/client.py", line 507, in get_experiment_by_name
    return self._tracking_client.get_experiment_by_name(name)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/_tracking_service/client.py", line 222, in get_experiment_by_name
    return self.store.get_experiment_by_name(name)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/store/tracking/rest_store.py", line 307, in get_experiment_by_name
    response_proto = self._call_endpoint(GetExperimentByName, req_body)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/store/tracking/rest_store.py", line 59, in _call_endpoint
    return call_endpoint(self.get_host_creds(), endpoint, method, json_body, response_proto)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/utils/rest_utils.py", line 197, in call_endpoint
    response = http_request(**call_kwargs)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/utils/rest_utils.py", line 105, in http_request
    raise MlflowException(
mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: API request to http://$DATABRICKS_HOST_URL/api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/get-by-name failed with timeout exception HTTPConnectionPool(host='$DATABRICKS_HOST_URL', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/get-by-name?experiment_name=%EXPERIMENTNAME%2Fpytorch-distributor (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fc83932af80>, 'Connection to $DATABRICKS_HOST_URL timed out. (connect timeout=120)')). To increase the timeout, set the environment variable MLFLOW_HTTP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT (default: 120, type: int) to a larger value.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 239, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1283, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1329, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1278, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1038, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 976, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 205, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 179, in _new_conn
    raise ConnectTimeoutError(
urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f3213206f80>, 'Connection to $DATABRICKS_HOST_URL timed out. (connect timeout=120)')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 815, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 815, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 815, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  [Previous line repeated 2 more times]
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='$DATABRICKS_HOST_URL', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/get-by-name?experiment_name=%EXPERIMENTNAME%2Fpytorch-distributor (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f3213206f80>, 'Connection to $DATABRICKS_HOST_URL timed out. (connect timeout=120)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/utils/rest_utils.py", line 93, in http_request
    return _get_http_response_with_retries(
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/utils/request_utils.py", line 131, in _get_http_response_with_retries
    return session.request(method, url, **kwargs)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 553, in send
    raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='$DATABRICKS_HOST_URL', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/get-by-name?experiment_name=%EXPERIMENTNAME%2Fpytorch-distributor (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f3213206f80>, 'Connection to $DATABRICKS_HOST_URL timed out. (connect timeout=120)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/utils/rest_utils.py", line 105, in http_request
    raise MlflowException(
mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: API request to http://$DATABRICKS_HOST_URL/api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/get-by-name failed with timeout exception HTTPConnectionPool(host='$DATABRICKS_HOST_URL', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/get-by-name?experiment_name=%EXPERIMENTNAME%2Fpytorch-distributor (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f3213206f80>, 'Connection to $DATABRICKS_HOST_URL timed out. (connect timeout=120)')). To increase the timeout, set the environment variable MLFLOW_HTTP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT (default: 120, type: int) to a larger value.
ERROR:torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api:failed (exitcode: 1) local_rank: 0 (pid: 4180) of binary: /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-4962ff4c-6fb8-44e9-a592-d7b22597989e/bin/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/run.py", line 766, in <module>
    main()
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/multiprocessing/errors/__init__.py", line 346, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/run.py", line 762, in main
    run(args)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/run.py", line 753, in run
    elastic_launch(
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 132, in __call__
    return launch_agent(self._config, self._entrypoint, list(args))
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 246, in launch_agent
    raise ChildFailedError(
torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.errors.ChildFailedError:

/tmp/tmpc8dg8q7l/train.py FAILED

Failures:
[1]:
  time      : 2023-09-14_15:56:41
  host      : 0817-210716-n00efkqi-10-52-173-109
  rank      : 1 (local_rank: 1)
  exitcode  : 1 (pid: 4181)
  error_file: <N/A>
  traceback : To enable traceback see: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/elastic/errors.html
[2]:
  time      : 2023-09-14_15:56:41
  host      : 0817-210716-n00efkqi-10-52-173-109
  rank      : 2 (local_rank: 2)
  exitcode  : 1 (pid: 4182)
  error_file: <N/A>
  traceback : To enable traceback see: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/elastic/errors.html
[3]:
  time      : 2023-09-14_15:56:41
  host      : 0817-210716-n00efkqi-10-52-173-109
  rank      : 3 (local_rank: 3)
  exitcode  : 1 (pid: 4183)
  error_file: <N/A>
  traceback : To enable traceback see: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/elastic/errors.html

Root Cause (first observed failure):
[0]:
  time      : 2023-09-14_15:56:41
  host      : 0817-210716-n00efkqi-10-52-173-109
  rank      : 0 (local_rank: 0)
  exitcode  : 1 (pid: 4180)
  error_file: <N/A>
  traceback : To enable traceback see: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/elastic/errors.html
```

Am I not supposed to use the workspace name? I'm really not sure which other [identifier](https://docs.databricks.com/en/workspace/workspace-details.html) I could be using. Is it my internet settings? Could my work proxy/VPN be somehow screwing things up in the browser? Is my output file path somehow screwed up? Thanks for all the help, really not sure where to go from here.